# Is there a way to use setdiff1d on 2D arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have an assignment to code kfold(n, n_folds) function, which is supposed to work exactly like sklearn.model_selection.KFold: divide list of integers from **1** to **n** into **n % k_folds** groups of **n // k_folds + 1** elements and **n - n % k** groups of **n // k_folds** elements (this part works well & optimized), then for each group get tuple (all integers from **1** to **n** not being part of the group, the group) My own realization of this last step just hits TL verdict hard (yet outputs correct answers).

```
def kfold(n, n_folds):
elements = np.arange(0, n)
slices = np.array(np.array_split(elements, n_folds))
ans = []
for slice in slices:
    ans.append((np.setdiff1d(elements, slice), slice))
return ans
```

kfold(10, 3) as example returns:

```
[([5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7]), ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10])]
```

I believe the problem is my code is not fully vectorized, employing one cycle instead of numpy methods. I've read documentation of **setdiff1d**, **setxor1d** and likewise functions. While they work well dividing a single slice, I cannot see a way to make them execute all the n_folds slices simultaneously. Is there a way to make this functions work? If there is a nice alternative solution, I'd like to hear about it too

Comment: To make your question easier to answer and the answers more useful to others this site encourages you to give a minimal reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case that would be 2d arrays of which you want to take a 2d `setdiff/setxor` and the desired result(s).

Comment: look at the code of those `set` functions.  They depend heavily on `unique` and `in1d` (which also uses `unique` and `sort`).  Those don't easily generalize to more dimensions.